# Overlap content in a fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox modal window that loads a page of content (a form).

On each input of the form there is a click event that shows a help tip to the right of the input.

My question is this - how can I make an element 'breakout' from the fancybox and overlap the edge, so that it's the highest element in the z-index?  I'd like the helptip to overlap the edge of the fancybox.

I've tried setting the help tip to z-index of 1,000,000 but it doesn't fix it. Is the fancybox script setting itself as the max z-index on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that another piece of script was messing with all the z-indexes on the page to try and work round the infamous [IE7 z-index issue](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ie7+z-index) - a little bit of jiggery pokery and all is now ok.

Gotta love picking up legacy code!

Comment: Can you please share what you did to fix this?

Comment: Hi Charlie, I had explained that in my answer - there was another script on the page that was resetting the z-index of all elements to get round the IE7 z-index bug, and I just had to work my calculations around that.  It looks like it might be something that's a problem in the latest version if you#re getting the same problem 2 years later...

Answer (score 1):

use firebug on firefox, or inspect the modal element in chrome to see it's css and look for the z-index for this fancybox modal window. Maybe it can help you solve the problem.

Comment: +1 Firebug is an incredibly useful tool for problems as simple as this.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that I've been using Firebug to work on this, but the z-index doesn't seem to be declared on the parent elements.  Could this be to with the way that fancybox loads external page content?  Is the content frame treated differently?

Comment: is your helptip element inside the fancy box?

Comment: Yup, the element is rendered inside the fancybox html.

Answer (score 1):

On line 298 there is:

```
tmp.wrapInner('<div style="width:' + w + ';height:' + h + ';overflow: ' + (selectedOpts.scrolling == 'auto' ? 'auto' : (selectedOpts.scrolling == 'yes' ? 'scroll' : 'hidden')) + ';position:relative;"></div>');
```

you need to remove:
`;overflow: ' + (selectedOpts.scrolling == 'auto' ? 'auto' : (selectedOpts.scrolling == 'yes' ? 'scroll' : 'hidden')) +` '

so that this line will look like:

```
tmp.wrapInner('<div style="width:' + w + ';height:' + h + ';position:relative;"></div>');
```

and then remove in css on the fancybox content the overflow atrribute.

Now your tooltips will work like they should.

I know that the author of fancybox v1 made there an if statement that will trun overflow auto/hidden to scroll or not to scroll but he should make if around the whole overflow param because thats whats is causing problems with overlaping.

Sorry for my poor english, Im in a rush.