# Overflow content in Fancybox

Tags: css, facebook-like, fancybox

I am using Fancy Box (fancybox.net) and I am having problems with over flowing content. I have a Facebook like button in my Fancy Box window, however whenever someone clicks "Like," the corresponding comment box the pops up, is cut off by the Fancy Box window. I don't want to increase the size of the Fancy Box window, however I would like this comment window to overlap itself and hang outside of the Fancy Box window. This should be fixed with some overflow:visible specifications, but thus far, my changes aren't having an effect. Anyone have ideas for letting this content fall outside of the window? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could post a link to a working demo of this so we can look at the code. One workaround would be to disable the comment box functionality of the comments box so that clicking the Facebook Like button just does what it says on the tin and Likes the page. Otherwise I'd imagine it may be a Z-Index problem so find the ID/Class of the main Faceboon comments element and try and work on that.

Comment: Hey Billy. Do you have an email address? Do not want to public the link publicly.

Comment: It is the exact same issue this person is having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108656/overlap-content-in-a-fancybox